# Entity component system for text-based console on Windows

Tags: c++, c++11, windows, entity-component-system

I have written this code base on [AsciiEngine](http://cecilsunkure.blogspot.com/2012/07/windows-console-game-ascii-engine.html). How can I improve this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>

#include <Windows.h>

enum class WorldSize
{
    ColNum = 80, // width
    RowNum = 50  // hieght
};

enum class Textures
{
    BackGround,
    Tile,
};

enum class Components
{
    Position,
    Sprite,
};

enum class Entities
{
    BackGround,
    Tile,
};

struct NonCopyable
{
    NonCopyable() = default;
    virtual ~NonCopyable() = default;

    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = (const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};

struct Vector2D
{
    float x, y;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
struct Random : public NonCopyable
{
    Random(float min, float max)
        : mUniformDistribution(min, max)
    {}

    T get() { return mUniformDistribution(mEngine); }

    std::default_random_engine mEngine{ std::random_device()() };

    template <typename U>
    static auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value, std::uniform_int_distribution<U>>::type;

    template <typename U>
    static auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value, std::uniform_real_distribution<U>>::type;

    decltype(dist<T>()) mUniformDistribution;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T, bool enable = std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value>
struct range_impl
{
    struct iterator
    {
        const T operator * () const noexcept{ return value; }

        iterator& operator ++() noexcept{ ++value; return *this; }

            friend  const bool operator != (const iterator& lhs, const iterator& rhs) noexcept{
            return lhs.value != rhs.value;
        }

        T value;
    };

    std::size_t size() const{ return last - first; }
    const iterator begin() const noexcept{ return{ first }; }
    const iterator end() const noexcept{ return{ last }; }

    T first, last;
};

template<typename T>
struct range_impl<T, false>
{
    range_impl(T first, T last) : first(first), last(last){}

    std::size_t size() const{ return std::distance(first, last); }
    const T begin() const noexcept{ return{ first }; }
    const T end() const noexcept{ return{ last }; }

    T first, last;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
range_impl<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> range(T1 first, T2 last) noexcept
{
    return{ first, last };
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Image : NonCopyable
{
    Image(Textures id_) 
        : id(id_)
        , mWidth()
        , mHeight()
        , mChar()
        , mColor()
    {}

    uint8_t chars(int x, int y)
    {
        return mChar[x + y * mWidth];
    }

    uint8_t colors(int x, int y)
    {
        return mColor[x + y * mWidth];
    }

    Image* loadFromFile(const std::string& fileName)
    {
        std::ifstream file(fileName);

        if (!file)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        file >> mWidth >> mHeight;

        mChar.resize(mWidth * mHeight);
        mColor.resize(mWidth * mHeight);

        for (const auto& i : range(0, mHeight))
        {
            for (const auto& j : range(0, mWidth))
            {
                int copy = 0;
                file >> copy;
                mChar[j + i * mWidth] = copy;

            }
        }

        for (const auto& i : range(0, mHeight))
        {
            for (const auto& j : range(0, mWidth))
            {
                int copy = 0;
                file >> copy;
                mColor[j + i * mWidth] = copy;
            }
        }

        return this;
    }
    Textures getId() const { return id; }
    std::string getIdReadable() { return toString(id); }

    friend struct Graphic;
private:
    std::string toString(Textures id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
        case Textures::BackGround:  return "BackGound";
        case Textures::Tile: return "Tile";
        default: return "UNKNOWN";
        }
    }
    Textures id;
    std::size_t mWidth;
    std::size_t mHeight;
    std::vector<uint8_t> mChar;
    std::vector<uint8_t> mColor;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename Identifier>
struct ResourceHolder
{
    static ResourceHolder<Identifier>* getInstance() { return &resourceHolderInstance; }

    void load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Image> resource(new Image(id));
        if (!resource->loadFromFile(filename))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("ResourceHolder::load - Failed to load " + filename);
        }

        insertResource(id, std::move(resource));
    }

    Image& get(Identifier id)
    {
        auto found = mResourceMap.find(id);
        assert(found != mResourceMap.end());
        return *found->second;
    }
    const Image& get(Identifier id) const
    {
        auto found = mResourceMap.find(id);
        assert(found != mResourceMap.end());
        return *found->second;
    }


private:
    static ResourceHolder<Identifier> resourceHolderInstance;

    void insertResource(Identifier id, std::unique_ptr<Image>& resource)
    {
        auto inserted = mResourceMap.insert(std::make_pair(id, std::move(resource)));
        assert(inserted.second);
    }

    std::unordered_map<Identifier, std::unique_ptr<Image>> mResourceMap;
};

using TexturesHolder = ResourceHolder<Textures>;

template <typename Identifier>
ResourceHolder<Identifier> ResourceHolder<Identifier>::resourceHolderInstance;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Graphic : NonCopyable
{
    Graphic(std::size_t width, std::size_t height)
        : mHeight(height)
        , mWidth(width)
        , mBuffer(width * height)
    {}
    static Graphic* getInstance() { return &graphicInstance; }

    bool screenBoundCheck(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x < static_cast<int>(mWidth) && x > -1 && y < static_cast<int>(mHeight) && y > -1) ? true : false;
    }

    bool writeImageToScreen(const Textures& id, int x, int y)
    {
        auto resourceHolder = TexturesHolder::getInstance();

        auto image = &resourceHolder->get(id);

        if (!image)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (const auto& i : range(0, image->mHeight)) 
        {
            for (const auto& j : range(0, image->mWidth))
            {
                if (screenBoundCheck(j + x, i + y) && image->mChar[j + image->mWidth * i] != 0 /*TRANSPERANT*/)
                {
                    mBuffer[(j + x) + mWidth * (i + y)].Char.AsciiChar = image->mChar[j + image->mWidth * i];
                    mBuffer[(j + x) + mWidth * (i + y)].Attributes = image->mColor[j + image->mWidth * i];
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    void clearScreen()
    {
        for (const auto& i : range(0, mHeight))
        {
            for (const auto& j : range(0, mWidth))
            {
                mBuffer[j + mWidth * i].Char.AsciiChar = 0;
                mBuffer[j + mWidth * i].Attributes = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void renderScreen()
    {
        COORD charBufferSize{ mWidth, mHeight };
        COORD characterPosition{ 0, 0 };
        SMALL_RECT writeArea{ 0, 0, mWidth - 1, mHeight - 1 };

        WriteConsoleOutputA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), mBuffer.data(), charBufferSize, characterPosition, &writeArea);
    }

private:
    static Graphic graphicInstance;

    std::vector<CHAR_INFO> mBuffer;
    std::size_t mHeight;
    std::size_t mWidth;
    const uint8_t TRANSPERANT = 255;

};

Graphic Graphic::graphicInstance(static_cast<std::size_t>(WorldSize::ColNum), static_cast<std::size_t>(WorldSize::RowNum));

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct ComponentHolder;

struct Entity : virtual NonCopyable
{
    Entity(Entities cid) : id(cid){}
    Entities getId() const { return id; }
    std::string getIdReadable(){return toString(id);}

    virtual void update(float dt) = 0;
    virtual void draw() = 0;

    std::shared_ptr<ComponentHolder> componentHolder;

    bool active = true;

private:
    std::string toString(Entities id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
        case Entities::BackGround:  return "BackGound";
        case Entities::Tile: return "Tile";
        default: return "UNKNOWN";
        }
    }
    Entities id;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Component : NonCopyable
{
    Component(Components cid) : id(cid), entity(nullptr), image(nullptr){};
    Component(Components cid, Entity *e, Image *i = nullptr) : id(cid), entity(e), image(i) {}

    Components getId() const { return id; }
    std::string getIdReadable() { return toString(id); }

    virtual void update(float dt) = 0;
    virtual void draw() = 0;

protected:
    Entity *entity;
    Image *image;

private:
    std::string toString(Components id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
        case Components::Position:  return "Position";
        case Components::Sprite: return "Sprite";
        default: return "UNKNOWN";
        }
    }
    Components id;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct ComponentHolder : NonCopyable
{
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Component>;

    template<typename T, typename... Targs>
    Component& addComponent(Targs&&... args)
    {
        Ptr ptr(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Targs>(args)...));

        auto inserted = mComponents.insert(std::make_pair(ptr->getId(), std::move(ptr)));

        return *inserted.first->second.get();
    }

    Component& getComponent(Components id)
    {
        auto found = mComponents.find(id);
        assert(found != mComponents.end());

        return *found->second;
    }
    const Component& getComponent(Components id) const
    {
        auto found = mComponents.find(id);
        assert(found != mComponents.end());

        return *found->second;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<Components, Ptr> mComponents;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Position : Component
{
    Position(Components cid, float x, float y) : Component(cid)
    {
        setPosition(x, y);
    }

    void setPosition(float x, float y)
    {
        position.x = x;
        position.y = y;
    }

    Vector2D getPosition() const
    {
        return position;
    }

    void update(float dt) override{};
    void draw() override {};

private:
    Vector2D position;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Sprite : Component
{
    Sprite(Components cid, Entity *e, Image *i) :Component(cid, e, i) {}

    void draw() override
    {
        auto graphic = Graphic::getInstance();

        auto position = dynamic_cast<Position*>(&entity->componentHolder->getComponent(Components::Position));

        if (image)
        {
            graphic->writeImageToScreen(image->getId(), static_cast<int>(position->getPosition().x), static_cast<int>(position->getPosition().y));
        }
    }

    void update(float dt) override {}
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct BackGround : Entity
{
    BackGround(Entities cid, float x, float y) :Entity(cid)
    {
        auto resourceHolder = TexturesHolder::getInstance();

        componentHolder = std::make_shared<ComponentHolder>();

        auto sprite = &componentHolder->addComponent<Sprite>(Components::Sprite, this, &resourceHolder->get(Textures::BackGround));
        auto position = &componentHolder->addComponent<Position>(Components::Position, x, y);
        // use sprite, position 
    }

    void update(float dt) override
    {

    }

    void draw() override
    {
        componentHolder->getComponent(Components::Sprite).draw();
    }
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Tile : Entity
{
    Tile(Entities cid, float x, float y) :Entity(cid)
    {
        auto resourceHolder = TexturesHolder::getInstance();

        componentHolder = std::make_shared<ComponentHolder>();

        auto sprite = &componentHolder->addComponent<Sprite>(Components::Sprite, this, &resourceHolder->get(Textures::Tile));
        auto position = &componentHolder->addComponent<Position>(Components::Position, x, y);
        // use sprite, position 
    }

    void update(float dt) override
    {

    }

    void draw() override
    {
        componentHolder->getComponent(Components::Sprite).draw();
    }
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct EntityManger : NonCopyable
{
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Entity>;

    template<typename T, typename... Targs>
    Entity& createEntity(Targs&&... args)
    {
        Ptr ptr(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Targs>(args)...));

        auto inserted = mEntities.insert(mEntities.end(), std::move(ptr));

        return **inserted;
    }

    void createFromFile(const std::string& fileName)
    {
        std::ifstream file(fileName);

        if (!file)
        {
            return;
        }

        std::vector<std::string> words;

        int index = 0;
        for (std::string word; file >> word;)
        {
            index++;
            words.push_back(word);

            if (index == 3)
            {
                if (words[0] == "BackGround")
                {
                    createEntity<BackGround>(Entities::BackGround, atof(words[1].c_str()), atof(words[2].c_str()));
                }
                else if (words[0] == "Tile")
                {
                    createEntity<Tile>(Entities::Tile, atof(words[1].c_str()), atof(words[2].c_str()));
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }

                index = 0;
                words.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    void update(float dt)
    {
        for (auto& i : mEntities)
        {
            if (!i->active)
            {
                deleteEntity(i);
            }

            i->update(dt); // dummy value
        }
    }

    void draw()
    {
        for (auto& i : mEntities)
        {
            if (!i->active)
            {
                deleteEntity(i);
            }

            i->draw();
        }
    }

    void deleteAll()
    {
        while (!mEntities.empty())
        {
            mEntities.back().release();
            mEntities.pop_back();
        }
    }

private:

    void deleteEntity(Ptr& entity)
    {
        auto it = std::find_if(mEntities.begin(), mEntities.end(),
            [&](Ptr& p)->bool
        {
            return entity->getId() == p->getId();
        });

        assert(it != mEntities.end());

        mEntities.erase(it);
    }

    std::vector<Ptr> mEntities;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Game : NonCopyable
{
    Game()
    {
        mEntities.createFromFile("../Game Assets/level.txt");
    }

    void run()
    {
        auto graphic = Graphic::getInstance();

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        while (true)
        {
            auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            double timeTakenInSeconds = (end - start).count()
                * (static_cast<double>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num)
                / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);

            if (timeTakenInSeconds > mWaitTime)
            {
                update();

                start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            }

            draw();

            graphic->renderScreen();
        }
    }

private:
    void update()
    {
        mEntities.update(0.f);
    }
    void draw()
    {
        mEntities.draw();
    }

    EntityManger mEntities;

    const double mWaitTime = 0.1;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

class FileSystem
{
public:

    void loadAllFiles(const std::string& directory)
    {
        WIN32_FIND_DATAA fileData = { 0 };
        std::string searchString = "*.txt";
        std::string entireSearchString = directory + searchString;

        HANDLE handle = FindFirstFileA(entireSearchString.data(), &fileData);

        do
        {
            loadFile(directory, fileData.cFileName);

        } while (FindNextFileA(handle, &fileData) != 0);
    }

    void loadFile(const std::string& folder, const std::string& fileName)
    {
        std::string file = folder + fileName;

        Textures id;

        if (fileName == "BackGround.txt")
        {
            id = Textures::BackGround;
        }
        else if (fileName == "Tile.txt")
        {
            id = Textures::Tile;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        auto resourceHolder = TexturesHolder::getInstance();

        resourceHolder->load(id, file);
    }
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    try
    {
        FileSystem file;
        file.loadAllFiles("../Game Assets/");

        Game game;
        game.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "An error occured." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

level.txt

> ```
> BackGround 
> 30.00 
> 5.00
>
> Tile 
> 31.00 
> 6.00
>
> Tile 
> 45.00 
> 6.00
>
> Tile 
> 31.00 
> 18.00
>
> Tile 
> 45.00 
> 18.00
> ```

BackGround.txt

> ```
> 17
> 15
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
> 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
>
> 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112
> 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 112 112 112 159 159 159 159 159 112 112 112 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112 159 159 159 112
> 112 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 112
> 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112 112
> ```

Tile.txt

> ```
> 1
> 1
> 219
>
> 10
> ```

Answer (score 1):

## Unnecessary overhead of `NonCopyable`

Because your `NonCopyable` has a virtual destructor, it forces any class inheriting from it to also become virtual: it will now need to have a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), which increases its size. Since you don't ever access your classes via the virtual base class, this is unnecessary overhead.

Also consider whether you need to make things non-copyable to begin with. For example, why is `Image` non-copyable? If you would make a copy of it, your program would continue to run perfectly fine, since everything stored in it is by value.

You also don't need to explicitly make a class non-copyable if it has member variables that are non-copyable. Consider `ComponentHolder`: it has this member:

```
std::unordered_map<Components, std::unique_ptr<Component>> mComponents;
```

Since `std::unique_ptr` is non-copyable, the `std::unordered_map` becomes non-copyable, and therefore `ComponentHolder` automatically becomes non-copyable.

There are other issues with your `NonCopyable`: it not only prevents copying, it is also non-movable since you deleted to move constructor (but not the move assignment operator?).

## Naming things

There are several questionable naming choices in your code. Consider `Textures`. Because it's the plural of a noun, it sounds like this is a collection of `Texture`s. But instead it is the ID of a texture. So I would name this `TextureID` (singular).

`Graphic` is a weird name, I think you would call this an `Image` instead, because apart from its member function `renderScreen()`, everything else is just image manipulation. Consider creating a `Screen` class that has a `renderImage(const Image &image)` member function, or at least rename `renderScreen()` to `renderToScreen()`.

Several names are just misleading: `writeImageToScreen()` doesn't write anything to the screen, it just copies a texture into the image buffer. So `copyTexture()` or `drawTexture()` would be better names.

Some things are not spelled correctly, like `TRANSPERANT` (should be `TRANSPARENT`), hieght (`height`), BackGound (BackGround) and occured (occurred). Consider enabling spell checking in your editor, and/or use a spell checking tool like [codespell](https://github.com/codespell-project/codespell).

## Use of `enum` for constants

An `enum` is a great way to give names to a set of possibilities, like IDs. But they are not a good fit for constants that have a specific value, like the number of rows and columns. Use `static constexpr` for those constants:

```
static constexpr std::size_t ColNum = 80;
static constexpr std::size_t RowNum = 50;
```

Note how you no longer need the `static_cast`s anymore when using these constants.

## Unnecessary use of `class`

In C++ you can have functions outside classes. If you have a `class` which has no state at all, and all its member functions could have been made `static`, you probably don't need to put them in a `class` at all. This is the case for example with `class FileSystem`. Just make free functions `loadFile()` and `loadAllFiles()`:

```
static void loadFile(const std::string& filder, const std::string& filename)
{
    ...
}

static void loadAllFiles(const std::string& directory)
{
    ...
    loadFile(directory, fileData.cFileName);
    ...
}

int main()
{
    try
    {    
        loadAllFiles("../Game Assets/");
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Arguably, `class Game` is also unnecessary; while it does have member variables, consider that these could have been made local variables inside `run()` instead, in which case there's just a single `run()` function that's only called once. So you could have made a free function `void runGame()` instead.

## Reading images

In `Image::loadFromFile()`, you use doubly-nested loops to read in the values from the file. However, since you are storing it in a one-dimensional `std::vector`, there is no need to do that, you can use a single `for`-loop instead. Furthermore, you con't need to first read it into an `int` and then copy it into the vector, you can do this instead:

```
mChar.resize(mWidth * mHeight);

for (const auto& c: mChar) {
    file >> c;
}
```

Note that calling `resize()` will actually cause all the elements in the vector to be value-initialized, but then you are going to overwrite them, so this is not optimal. It's not really important here, but the best way would be to call [`reserve()`](https://com) instead of `resize()`, and then `push_back()` the values you read in. You can also the [STL algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) [`std::copy_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) in combination with [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to read in the file without any loops:

```
mChar.reserve(mWidth * mHeight);
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>(file), mWidth * mHeight,
            std::back_inserter(mChar));
```

But probably a simple `for`-loop is more clear here.

## Unnecessary abstractions

Your `class ResourceHolder`, on closer inspection, is just a wrapper around a `std::unordered_map`. It doesn't add any important features, apart from perhaps a `getInstance()` function. But instead of creating a singleton class, in C++ you can just declare a global variable:

```
static std::unordered_map<TextureID, Image> textureHolder;
```

Note that instead of using "`Holder`" in the name, I would use the plural of the type to indicate that this is a collection of things, so:

```
static std::unordered_map<TextureID, Image> textures;
```

Instead of `TexturesHolder::getInstance().load(id, filename)`, consider that you can just write:

```
textures.emplace(id, id);
textures[id].loadFromFile(filename);
```

Or with C++17 you can write:

```
resources.emplace(id, id).loadFromFile(filename);
```

Note that there is no need to use `std::unique_ptr` here; `std::unordered_map` already manages the memory for the keys and values it stores.

Instead of `get()`, you can use `at()` directly on the map:

```
auto& image = textures.at(id); // or textures[id] if you don't need bounds checking
```

The same goes for `ComponentHolder`.

## Missing error checking

In `loadFromFile()`, you check if the file was opened correctly, but you didn't do any further error checking. Consider that errors can happen *at any time* when reading or writing files; these could be actual I/O errors, but it can also be that the contents of the file are not what you expected.

While checking for errors after every little I/O operations would be very tedious, luckily stream object remember their error state. So you can read everything like you already did, but only check at the end that everything was read correctly:

```
Image* loadFromFile(const std::string& fileName)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName):

    file >> mWidth >> mHeight;
    ...

    return file ? this : nullptr;
}
```

Beware though that if reading `mWidth` or `mHeight` fails, those variables might not be written to. Since you never initialized those variables, they can contain random values. Either add a check that `file.good()` right after reading these two, or ensure they are initialized to zero before trying to read them.

## `throw` early

If you are using exceptions, then `throw` as soon as you encounter an error. The benefit of exceptions are that code that cannot directly handle the error doesn't have to deal with error conditions, they can just leave it up some higher layer to `catch` the exception. Consider `loadFromFile()`: it potentially returns a `nullptr`, so in `ResourceHolder::load()` you had to check for an error condition. If you would instead a `throw std::runtime_error` directly from `loadFromFile`, then `load()` wouldn't need to do any error handling.

Another benefit is that you can then pass a filename to the constructor of `Image`, so you could have simplified `load()` to:

```
void load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename) {
    insertResource(id, std::make_unique<Image>(id, filename));
}
```

Or if you removed `ResourceHolder` and just used global map variables, then with C++17 you could have written:

```
textures.try_emplace(id, id, filename);
```

## Beware of iterator invalidation

When you are iterating over a container, be careful when adding or removing items at the same time, as these can cause the iterator to be invalidated. This happens in `update()` and `draw()`. Even worse, those functions seem to explicitly dereference the iterators after deleting the item they point to! One possible solution is to use [`std::erase_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) to erase inactive elements, and then to iterate over the remaining ones:

```
void update(float dt) {
    std::erase_if(mEntities, [](auto& entity) {
        return !entity->active;
    });

    for (auto& entity: mEntities) {
        entity->update(dt);
    }
}
```

You could optimize this by keeping track of whether any entities were deactivated since the last call to `update()`, so that you can avoid having to call `std::erase_if()` unnecessarily. Even more advanced would be to check if an element is active in the `for`-loop, and if not swap it with the last element; this wouldn't invalidate any iterators, and at the end of the loop all the inactive elements are at the end. If you kept a count, you can then simply `resize()` the vector to get rid of them.

## Do you need an Entity Component System?

At the moment, your code only draws tiles. Instead of using an [ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) for that, I think it would be better to implement a tilemap renderer. This would be a single entity in a game, optimized at rendering the map using tiles, instead of having many individual tile entities in the ECS.